# How can I append an attribute selector on jquery object?

Tags: jquery

I have assigned a jquery object to a variable named `$all_messages`

I am also going to be filtering it with an id but can't seem to find a way to do that using the variable $all_messages. I have been looking all over but can't find a way.

If anyone can show me how to do that I would really appreciate it.

Below is my code I am using

```
var all_messages = $(".message");
all_messages.hide();

msg_toggle.on("click", function () {
  var id =  $(this).attr("id");

  //all_messages.$("[id='"+id+"']"); is not working :(
  var message = all_messages.$("[id='"+id+"']");

  if(message.is(":hidden")){
    $(message).slideDown(300);
  } else {
    $(message).slideUp(300);
  }

  return false;
```

Comment: IDs **must** be _unique_.

Comment: all_messages.find('#<insert id here>'); ID's have to be unique. You could use classname instead,